# python - combinig two unequal lists and create a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

can you let me know how I can do the below

```
a = ['x']

b = ['y', 'z']
```

I want to combine the above 2 list and create dictionary like below

```
c = {'x': ['y', 'z']}
```

I tried below code but that didn't work

```
from itertools import cycle

c = dict(zip(a, cycle(b)))
```

output:

```
c = {'x': 'y'}
```

Comment: I think you need to do a better job of explaining what the rules are for combining the list.

Comment: What would you expect from `a = ['x', 'y']` and `b = ['y', 'z', 'a', 'b']`?

Comment: You can do `c = {a[0] : b}` but I'm guessing you want something more general?

Comment: what result do you expect if you will have `a = ['a','b','c']`

Answer (score 1):

`a` just contain one key? If so, create it directly:

```
a = ['x']
b = ['y', 'z']

d = {a[0]: b}

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do really need to provide more details...
If you are looking to step through pairs of `b` then you can:

```
>>> a = ['x']
>>> b = ['y', 'z']
>>> x = iter(b)
>>> dict(zip(a, zip(x, x)))
{'x': ('y', 'z')}
```

But `len(a)` must equal `len(b)//2`, or you can cycle through `b`:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> a = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> b = ['y', 'z']
>>> x = it.cycle(b)
>>> dict(zip(a, zip(x, x)))
{'x': ('y', 'z'), 'y': ('y', 'z'), 'z': ('y', 'z')}
```

Or with multiple pairs of `b`:

```
>>> a = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> x = it.cycle(b)
>>> dict(zip(a, zip(x, x)))
{'x': ('a', 'b'), 'y': ('c', 'd'), 'z': ('a', 'b')}
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work just fine:

```
a = ['x']
b = ['y','z']
c = dict(a=b)
print(c)
```

Is there a reason you're importing cycle for a function Python has built-in?

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want??

[image]

You do not have to use any of that import library.

1. A dictionary is a data type, you can use c = {} to create that, just like other type (ex: a = [] to create a list)
2. I assume you have more than one items in list a and you want to combie it with b....b(more than one list). So i have a for loop there.
3. Please mention your python version (Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 have slightly different syntax)

**UPDATE 1:**

Example Code:

```
a = ['x']
b = ['y', 'z']
c = {}
for i in a:
    c[i] = b

print c
```

Comment: I am trying to show a new programmer correctly and fully way to do this. Better one is a video and second is a image. It's not possible to recreate entire same situation with all possible solution and information (e.g python version, code, test print and result) if use `CODE`

Comment: Video would be even worse. The idea is to make it _easy_ for other people to copy and use the code you provide, not more difficult. If you think it's impossible to do a reasonable job with just text, I suggest you practice until you get the hang of it.